# Cloud SQL PHP login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-app-engine, cloud

Just a quick question:

I have a Google App Engine (website) and a Cloud SQL instance attached to it. I have a database that is connected to the website.

What is the easiest way to have a PHP login for that? for example a user database on the Cloud SQL instance. I know how to do it normally but am just starting out on the cloud so am unsure how to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Hey..well I am stuck on where to start. I know normal php login forms etc for a local server. But as the cloud is a little different I really don't know where to start!

Comment: Unfortunately "where to start" questions are not good SO questions. We're here to help each other when we run into a problem with something we've tried, rather than starting from scratch. Having said that, creating a login with PHP is no different on the cloud...it all starts with a database connection.

Comment: The main problem I am having is with sessions, do sessions work the same?

Comment: You didn't mention that, sessions work exactly the same and are easily testable.

Comment: Please check my latest question there is more information:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126033/gae-php-form-not-working